# Add key and incremental values to array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I want to add another property to each of the objects but I want the value to be incremental in nature. I want each to be 5 more than the other.

My array of objects:

```
let arr_obj = [
   {
     name: 'Hermione',
     order: 'books',
   },
   {
     name: 'Harry',
     order: 'brooms',
   },
   {
     name: 'Ron',
     order: 'food',
   }
]
```

I want to add another property to each of the objects in the array and want the value to be 25 less the previous one.

So what I want my object to look like (expected result):

```
arr_obj = [
   {
     name: 'Hermione',
     order: 'books',
     order_size: 100,
   },
   {
     name: 'Harry',
     order: 'brooms',
     order_size: 75, //100-25  
   },
   {
     name: 'Ron',
     order: 'food',
     order_size: 50, //75-25   
   }
]
```

I tried a forEach but that is not working. It does not subtract the 25.

```
let order_size = 100;
arr_obj.forEach(d => {
   d['order_size'] = order_size-25;
});
```

When I do this, I am getting:

```
arr_obj = [
   {
     name: 'Hermione',
     order: 'books',
     order_size: 100,
   },
   {
     name: 'Harry',
     order: 'brooms',
     order_size: 100,
   },
   {
     name: 'Ron',
     order: 'food',
     order_size: 100,
   }
]
```

How do I get the expected result?

Comment: Try `order_size -= 25`

Comment: No, that is not what you are getting. But indeed if you do the same `order_size-25` over and over again, it is always going to give the same result (75, not 100). You must *update* `order_size` to be 25 less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to modify order_size on each iteration. try this:

```js
let arr_obj = [
       {
         name: 'Hermione',
         order: 'books',
       },
       {
         name: 'Harry',
         order: 'brooms',
       },
       {
        name: 'Ron',
        order: 'food',
       }
    ];

let order_size = 100;
arr_obj.forEach(d => {
   d['order_size'] = order_size;
   order_size -= 25;
});
console.log(arr_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

The forEach method will also give you a key (numeric value that increments by one for each item) you can use this to do any necessary incrementing or decrementing of values in an array.

for example if you want a value that increases by 5 each time

```
arr_obj.forEach( (item, key) => {
  item.newValue = key*5
});
```

or if you want to reduce a value by 25 each time:

```
arr_obj.forEach( (item, key) => {
  item.order_size = 100 - (key*25)
});
```

This is possibly better practice than updating any variable outside of the current function