# Why is my function for adding key and incremental values to array of objects returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

In relation to my previous question: [Add key and incremental values to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787551/add-key-and-incremental-values-to-array-of-objects)

@ran.t 's solution worked perfectly. But now I am trying to write a function to reuse the solution, I am getting undefined.

No function:

```js
let arr_obj = [
       {
         name: 'Hermione',
         order: 'books',
       },
       {
         name: 'Harry',
         order: 'brooms',
       },
       {
        name: 'Ron',
        order: 'food',
       }
    ];

let order_size = 100;
arr_obj.forEach(d => {
   d['order_size'] = order_size;
   order_size -= 25;
});
console.log(arr_obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Calling using the function (need for resuability):

```js
let arr_obj = [
       {
         name: 'Hermione',
         order: 'books',
       },
       {
         name: 'Harry',
         order: 'brooms',
       },
       {
        name: 'Ron',
        order: 'food',
       }
    ];

let order_size = 100;

const myFnc = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(d => {
   d['order_size'] = order_size;
   order_size -= 25;
  });
}
console.log(myFnc(arr_obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why am I getting `undefined` when all I am doing is putting the forEach inside the function?

Comment: `myFnc` has no `return` statement, it modifies the argument array in place.

Comment: Put `return arr;` at the end of `myFnc` or use `console.log(arr_obj)`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, if you add it as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Someone already posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return `arr`, bro.